# ending a void method with return;

Tags: java, methods, void

In my textbook it mentions that whenever you want to immediately end a void method you can introduce return; However, I tried implementing it on eclipse and it doesn't seem to work. I am trying to end the method at the variable day. I get an error message saying that the rest of my code is unreachable.

```
public void readInput(){
    Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the day");
    day = myKeyboard.nextInt();
    return; //error is here
    System.out.println("Enter the year");
    year = myKeyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the month");
    month = myKeyboard.next();
}
```

Is there something that my textbook forget to mention !?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? What don't you understand about the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Java, [it's illegal to include code that can't ever possibly be executed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) (because this is nearly always an error). In your code, you're calling `return` unconditionally, and then you have extra code after that--this is called **unreachable code**, and it's causing the compiler error.

The use of `return` in the middle of the method is for when you have a conditional, such as

```
if(exitNow) { 
    return;
}
```

and the program might otherwise continue on to the remaining code.  To test this out, try this:

```
if(day == 0) {
    return;
}
```

As @fdreger mentioned, the JLS specifically says that even if the condition of an `if` statement is a compile-time constant, the compiler treats the `if` as though the condition were uncertain (this applies only to `if`, and not to `do`, `while`, or `for` loops), so this would make your code compile:

```
if(true) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll get an error message on the line right after the return, because you can never get there.   Try something like:

```
if(some condition)
{
   return;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote.    chrylis's answer showed up as I hit enter on mine.

Comment: I don't think you got downvoted but unupvoted; I got one too for some reason. *shrug*

Comment: No big deal. I just wondered if there was something wrong, other than both of us providing pretty much the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are right and complete - javac will not compile code that is trivially unreachable, so you cannot just put a `break` or `throw` statement in the middle of your code. However, since sometimes that's exactly what you want to do (eg because you are testing something) you can benefit from the fact that the test is not very thorough. Something like this will do:

```
if (2+2==4) return;
```

Comment: This seems odd to most people, and the JLS section I linked to in my answer has a couple of paragraphs explaining why this is okay. In fact, `if(true) return;` is perfectly legal.

Comment: yep, I know (assuming you mean `if (true) return;`); I just like the 2+2==4 version so much better :-) It feels like winking and reminds me that this is just a test.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is correct. The rest of your code is unreachable. Specifically this section:

```
System.out.println("Enter the year");
year = myKeyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter the month");
month = myKeyboard.next();
```

It is "unreachable" because the return statement will cause it to return from the function.

If you are looking to test returning from the method after

```
day = myKeyboard.nextInt();
```

Just remove the return and comment out the other section.

```
public void readInput(){
    Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the day");
    day = myKeyboard.nextInt();
    // System.out.println("Enter the year");
    // year = myKeyboard.nextInt();
    // System.out.println("Enter the month");
    // month = myKeyboard.next();
}
```

Or delete it entirely. I am assuming you wanted to put in the return because you were testing something or otherwise want to also do the year/month later.